# Why does LANG change the output of str.encode()

Tags: python, python-3.x

This command returns `b'?'`, as expected since "α" is not in the ISO-8859-1 encoding.

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 python -c "print('α'.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'replace'))"
```

This command returns `b'\xce\xb1'`, which I don't understand.

```
LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1 python -c "print('α'.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'replace'))"
```

What is causing this? What I am trying to do is remove characters not in an encoding (here ISO-8859-1), replacing them with `?`, as I think this code should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not changing the output of `str.encode`; it's changing the encoding of `sys.stdin`.

```
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 python -c "print(__import__('sys').stdin.encoding)"
UTF-8
$ LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1 python -c "print(__import__('sys').stdin.encoding)"
ISO-8859-1
```

As a result, Python interprets the UTF-8 `b'\xce\xb1'` from your terminal as literal bytes:

```
$ LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1 python3 -c "print(len('α'))"
2
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 python3 -c "print(len('α'))"                 
1
```

Comment: True, but I don't see why that would make a difference. The command `print(len('α'.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'replace')))` returns `1` with UTF-8 and `2` with ISO-8859-1, so it is not the print statement causing the difference.